Pytubefix Downloaded videos are not playing
from pytubefix import YouTube


url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eKqlLNNCUY8&ab_channel=BonusGamer"

yt = YouTube(url)

yt.streams.get_by_itag('134').download()

I used this code for just to try the pytube. The video is downloading correctly.
When I try to play it, Player shows the duration of the video correctly but nothing playing any suggestions ?
Edit: I see that when I try to download 360p or higher there is no problem but why lower resolutions has problem ?
